# Можно ли реализовать в проекте на Yii2 механизм аналогичный middleware Laravel, и как?

Tags: yii2, role, middleware

В проекте на Yii2 необходимо разделить по ролям доступ юзеров. Функционал проекта большой и прописывать в behaviors для каждой роли в каждом нужном контроллере слишком времязатратный процесс. Я новичок в Yii, до этого юзал Laravel и механизм миддлварей например для группы роутов очень удобный. Подскажите, есть ли варианты реализации такого в Yii, может есть родные инструменты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разделите ваше приложение на модули и прямо в конфиге вы сможете определить права доступа

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => app\modules\User\Module::className(),
        'as access' => [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'controllers'=>['user/auth'],
                        'actions'=>['login', 'captcha'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?']                        
                    ],                   
                    // И так далее
                ]
            ]
]
```

Comment: RBAC: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md